# JQuery Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fadeToggle is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I've been getting back into coding and am new to rails and jQuery.  I just recently ran into a problem when migrating my mobile navigation to a shim.

The jQuery I use to create a full screen overlay works on my home page but when I navigate to a subsequent static page the same script does not work and I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fadeToggle is not a function
```

Basic file structure:

My "home page" is in `app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb` and the `link_to` page I referred to is also in `app/views/static_pages/donation.html.erb`.

The navigation that is in `app/layouts/_header.html.erb` looks like the following:

```
<div class="brand">
  <%= link_to image_tag("logo.png",alt: "The Eric Scherbarth Leukemia Research Foundation Inc.", class: "logo"), "https://www.eslrf.org" %>
</div>
<nav id="main-nav">
  <%= link_to "Home", root_path, :class => "nav-item"%>
  <%= link_to "Eric's Story", '#', :class => "nav-item"%>
  <%= link_to "Our Mission", '#', :class => "nav-item"%>
  <%= link_to "Events", '#', :class => "nav-item"%>
  <%= link_to "Contact Us", '#', :class => "nav-item"%>
  <%= link_to "Donate Now", donations_path, :class => "donate-btn" %>
</nav>
<div class="responsive-btn">
  <a href="#" class="btn-open"></a>
</div>

<!-- Mobile and Responsive Navigation Overlay -->
<div class="overlay">
<div class="overlay-wrapper">
  <nav class="responsive-nav">
    <%= link_to "Home", root_path, :class => "responsive-nav-item" %>
    <%= link_to "Eric's Story", '#', :class => "responsive-nav-item"%>
    <%= link_to "Our Mission", '#', :class => "responsive-nav-item"%>
    <%= link_to "Events", '#', :class => "responsive-nav-item"%>
    <%= link_to "Contact Us", '#', :class => "responsive-nav-item"%>
    <div class="btn-container">
      <%= link_to "Donate Now", donations_path, method: :get, :class => "responsive-donate-btn" %>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="social">
      <div class="social-icon">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="social-icon">
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="social-icon">
        <a href="https://www.twitter.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="social-icon">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And the Jquery script looks like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".responsive-btn a").click(function(){
          $(".overlay").fadeToggle(200);
        $(this).toggleClass('btn-open').toggleClass('btn-close');
    });
    $('.overlay').on('click', function(){
        $(".overlay").fadeToggle(200);
        $(".responsive-btn a").toggleClass('btn-open').toggleClass('btn-close');
        open = false;
    });
});
```

I have disabled turbolinks at this point as I was running into issues with the script working with turbolinks activated.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In what line does the error occured

Comment: The error occurs in the  $(".overlay").fadeToggle(200); within the first function

Comment: Can you try `$(".overlay:first").fadeToggle(200);`

Comment: Sorry for the delay but I didn't have access to try the code until now.  Unfortunately it did not help, still getting the same error.  Could it be before my script is within app/assets/javascripts/static_pages.js however the html is located within app/assets/views/layouts/_header.html.erb?

Comment: I just realized that the page in which the error occurs contains other script.  specifically a form that is generated by a provider called donate.ly.  I'm wodnering if that script is causing issues with my navigation script...

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I had the same issue today. In my case it was due to swapping jquery 'standard' with the 'slim' version, swapping it back fixed it. Posting on here for reference.